# High power SMPS brownout runtime?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

We've been told by our electricity grid that we need to be able to demonstrate that we won't dump our load during a low voltage condition of 0.7x (of 240V - 168V) for up to 2 seconds on a 3000W SMPS. Obviously, it's hard to get this sort of data from PSU spec sheets but I'm curious as to how one can determine input capacitance and run time given a brownout condition on an SMPS that's rated to a cutoff voltage of say 200V.

What would be the expected behaviour of say, a flyback converter operating at 200kHz? Would it be likely to shut down completely at 168V or ride through given input capacitance?

Comment: Add a specification of PSU.

Comment: Is there any way you can test it and see? 3000W is quite a few watts but not an insane number - you could presumably rig something up to switch it onto a 168V transformer for 2 seconds and see what happens. Note that I have no experience or knowledge in this area.

Comment: 2 seconds is more than one order of magnitude longer than a regular consumer or industrial power supply. May I ask where this is used? You are approaching supercapacitor territory with this.

Comment: @winny When the power company says "don't dump your load" I doubt they care whether your equipment continues operating; what they do care about, presumably, is whether your equipment keeps drawing power from the grid, rather than shutting down completely.

Comment: Still strange. What do they expect? 99.999 % of power supplies in the world would shutdown from that low and long brownout. It would be easier to make it have wide enough input voltage range to ride though it at low voltage than to do a 3 kW 2 second capacitor bank (huge!).

Comment: My thoughts exactly - the application is a bitcoin miner and this is an annoying requirement of the particular grid operator who doesn't appear to have their power security under control, but yes they've requested 0.7 nominal voltage for 2 seconds and that's a lot of capacitor or UPS...,

Comment: Very strange grid code. I bet a UPS or just lower your minimum input voltage requirement will be the cheapest option.